# Picture of engaged spouse

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, nikah

Is it allowed in islam to keep a photo of engaged spouse and look at it whenever groom likes? i know there is no concept called engagement but somehow in our case this has happened, so wondering is it ok.

Is it possible to at least to visit her place when parents around to talk?

I personally feel like it is kind of odd to get married to someone I don’t know much, didn’t people talk and get to know each other in prophet time?

Answer (score 1):

Before nikah, you are a non-mahram for her. so the same rules of non-mahram applies to you. you cannot look at her picture.

The only condition for you to look at her picture anytime, is, when you do nikah with her, otherwise never.

Regarding talking to her, before nikah, you can talk to her once or twice, but only in presence of her parents or wali. it is better not to visit her multiple time or talk to her too much.

You follow a western concept that you MUST know your wife, befoer marriage. this concept is not islamic. in islam, you dont know if she is good or bad for you. You just have to marry her, withotu knowing her, because its Allah, who knows better than you, that if she is better for you or not. If you want to take guidance from Allah, then do istakhara before engagment (or giving her your word that you will marry her). Once you do, then dont turn back.  Because the more you will know her, their are more chances that you will fall in love with her and you might like/dislike many of her habits (which is natutral), for which you can change your decision. so stay away from this evil concept of KNOWING girl before marriage properly. and put your trust in Allah. In sha Allah, Allah will do the best for both of you.

And Allah knows the best.

Comment: This is not correct; there is nothing in Islam that says "you should marry people without knowing them" (either for the man or for the woman). This is simply wrong. Islam prohibits _extra_ conversations/contact because this may possibly lead to _sin_ and it is the responsibility of every muslim to protect themselves from sin.  Knowing your spouse, talking with them (in the presence of elders/wali - again, to prevent temptation); looking at her; etc. is all allowed if your intention is to get married; and this intention is supported by her elders and your elders.

Comment: Brother, It is common sense that what does "knowing them" means. the questionnaire is trying to say something else.. and Ofcourse its obvious that if you dont know them, how can you marry them? by knowing, obviously it means that knowing Too much, about her, through Haram way or crossing the limits of islam. one exampple is , Sometimes even people goto an extenet that they sleep with girl to know if she is good in bed or not. I hope i have made it clear now

Comment: I think i must make my point very clear. what i meant is, our interaction was only once while elders and parents were around and then marriage got fixed. so by this question i intended to know whether it is allowed keep the respective parties picture with me in case if i feel to see, because nikah is scheduled for next year. also if possible to speak and get to know  a little more, as we could not talk anything important at first time. just to get to know the interests and etc. and by any means, i did not seek to the extent brother farhan pointed out. may allah safe guard us.

Comment: @ahamedhassan: the answer is no,its not allowed. you cannot keep her picture, and cannot talk to her in private.

Answer (score 0):

We have to meet and interact with so many women every day whether it be at work / school or other public places and islam allow to do so as long as we maintain certain principles and certain level of respect. And yet when it comes to someone we are actually wanting to marry, all of a sudden we can't do any of that. How is that even possible brother?

Even mufti Menk said you can meet her as many times as you want as long as there is a chaperone present